# Getting error while populating date value using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am getting error while populating date value in date field

I have the date input field,

```
<input type="date" data-ng-model="personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.dob" name="dob" value="{{personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.dob}}" pattern="dd/MM/YYYY"/>
```

I am getting the DOB value from server like this,

```
$scope.kycinfo  = {
   "title": "Mr",
   "name": "vishnu",
   "dob": "22-06-1980",
  };
```

I am getting error When i try to set the value like this,

```
$scope.personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.dob = $scope.kycinfo.dob;
```

Error saying, **Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `22-06-1980` to be a date**

Comment: You don't need `value` attribute when you are using `ng-model`

Comment: i removed, but how do i set the value in input field

Comment: type='date' model need date type value your are providing him string type value

Comment: set `dob` as a date type

Answer (score 1):

If you are using moment.js (if not use it), then try this

```
$scope.personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.dob = moment($scope.kycinfo.dob);
```

otherwise using simple javascript (not recommended)

```
$scope.personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.dob = new Date($scope.kycinfo.dob);
```

Also no need of value attribute when you are already using ng-model